# Move SharePoint Designer workflow from one document library to another

Tags: sharepoint, workflow

I built a sharepoint workflow for a "test" document library.  I would now like to move this workflow to a "prod" document library.  I copied the workflow in sharepoint designer from one document library to the next successfully.  However when I bring up the wizard and try to change the document library the workflow was made for I am unable because the drop down box with this option is disabled.

Does anyone know how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once an association has been made in SharePoint Designer, the only way to change it is through the workflow's .xoml.wfconfig.xml file.

Find:

```
<Association ListID="..." TaskListID="..." ... ></Association>
```

Now you can do two things:

1) Edit the association completely within the XML.

or

2) Remove the association within the XML and then open the wizard.  It should let you select a new list. **DO NOT leave the first page of the wizard if you do this though.** Just select the list and hit Finish (i.e.: save and exit). If you change pages in the wizard all of your field references will become invalid. After you save and exit, feel free to use the full functionality of the wizard upon re-entering the wizard.

Answer (score 0):

Have you double checked the permissions on the new Document Library to ensure you have sufficient privledges?

Answer (score 0):

One more point to note is that, once restored, review every step of the workflow as references to variables or fields may have been replaced by GUID.
For example, if there was a step to send email to a user, it may have been replaced by a GUID. You just need to re-assign the user.